# iOS - Call specific keyboard from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uikeyboard

Is there a way to turn a keyboard name into a UIKeyboardType or some other type that can be used as a keyboard?

Here's what I have. Assuming the device has a specific language keyboard installed (say Japanese), I can check NSUserDefaults and get a list of devices, like this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfKeyboardNames = [defaults arrayForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"];
```

This, in my case, returns 4 keyboard names:

```
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
"emoji@sw=Emoji",
"ja_JP-Kana@sw=Kana;hw=US",
"ru_RU@sw=Russian"
```

And then what I want to do is set the keyboard of `ja_JP-Kana@sw=Kana;hw=US` as the input type of a UITextField.
Ideally this will be made for the entire app and not just a field, but for now this might work.

The problem is the UITextField accepts only an enum as keyboardType, and this is clearly not an enum value.

Is there a way to do this?
The final result should be the Japanese keyboard shows up when the user touches the UITextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API that lets you switch keyboards. It is completely under the control of the user by tapping the little globe key on the keyboard.

The `UITextInputMode` class provides a way to see what keyboards are available but no API to set it.

Comment: But if you know there's a keyboard installed on the device, is there no way to call that keyboard? I know this isn't a public API and might get rejected anyway.

Comment: I have no idea if there is a private API to do this. If there is and you use it, your app will be rejected.